# Release a file created by NetLogo while NetLogo open

Tags: r, netlogo, igraph

Eventually I will be wanting to use RNetLogo to pass a NetLogo network to R so that R can do some network analysis using the packages igraph and keyplayer or influenceR and then pass the results back to NetLogo. I am currently running both NetLogo and R separately so that I can make sure my R code works before putting it into the format needed by RNetLogo.

I am creating the network in NetLogo and passing to igraph, but igraph is temperamental about graph formatting. The best format to transfer appears to be gml but the NetLogo network extension for saving gml doesn't satisfy the igraph requirements.

I have written a simple gml export. Looks like:

```
to export-simple-gml
  carefully [ file-delete "temp.gml" ] [ ]
  file-open "temp.gml"
  file-print "graph" file-print "["
  file-print "  directed 0"
  ask turtles
  [ file-print "  node" file-print "  ["
    file-type "    id " file-print who
    file-print "  ]"
  ]
  ask links
  [ let source one-of both-ends
    let target [other-end] of source
    file-print "  edge" file-print "  ["
    file-type "    source " file-print [who] of source
    file-type "    target " file-print [who] of target
    file-print "  ]"
  ]
  file-print "]"
  file-close
end
```

The R import code is very straightforward:

```
library(igraph)
gg <- read_graph(file = "temp.gml", format = "gml")
```

This all works if I have R closed when I run the NetLogo function, then close NetLogo and open R to import. However, if I have R open after previously testing the import, it fails. If I have not closed NetLogo, the import fails. If I have R open when I export from NetLogo, the export text is appended instead of replacing the file.

Is there any way from NetLogo to force the file to be released? Alternatively, is there any way from R to override the control of the (closed but not released) file by NetLogo?

Comment: As an aside: the built-in NW extension has a gml exporter: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/nw.html#save

Comment: I know it does, but igraph won't read the file that's created. That's why I simplifed the output.

Comment: Ah, that's somewhat problematic. Does igraph give you an error? If there's a problem with nw's output, I'd like to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce this problem but failed in doing so. I'm using

- NetLogo 5.3 (Mac OS X)
- R 3.2.3
- igraph 1.0.1

I also tried writing and reading CSV's using R's `read.csv`. I couldn't replicate the exact problem you described. Is it possible you're opening the file anywhere other than this procedure? Are your versions of any of the above different?

One thing I did notice is that when a file primitive errors, the file is left open which can cause the above procedure to write an invalid gml file. I would suggest calling `file-close` or `file-close-all` at the top of that function, just like you do with `file-delete`.

Comment: hi Robert. My apologies, now I can't reproduce it. I am wondering if it was connected to an appending instead of replacing problem I originally had and I simply had a corrupt file somewhere. I should go back and see if I can make it read the nw extension gml export too. I will leave the question a few days in case the problem returns and add more details if needed.

Comment: @JenB: are you on Windows by any chance? Windows is far more finicky than Linux or OS X about multiple processes accessing open files.

Comment: I am indeed on Windows. Windows 7 here and I will check on my home machine (W8.1) when I get home. But the problem is at least temporarily not reproducible, even by me.

Comment: I have decided that the problem was probably errors leaving the file open as you noticed. I can't seem to reproduce it now that I have a simplified gml export and am no longer getting such file errors.